# caffe iteration=0 being stuck

Tags: centos, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

[image]

Issue summary

The procedure stopped at the command "Iteration 0,Testing net {#0}" (I'm a rookie,waiting for your guidance online,Thx)

Steps to reproduce

After i modified the network file in  `'/home/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt'`
command:

```
./examples/mnist/train_lenet.sh
```

......running......

> ```
> [...solver.cpp 349] Iteration 0, Testing net {#0}
> ```

|-_-|

My system configuration

Operating system:CentOS 7
caffe :CPU-only

Comment: is it possible you are using the same input layer for train and test? i.e., same leveldb/lmdb?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/38348801/1714410